# How can I use IQueryable<T>.Include with Inheritance

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I think I use TPT inheritance. I have an abstract parent class and three subclasses. What I want is a basic find function, but I need to explicitly do includes. My problem is how can I include different properties based on the type.

```
public List<RandomObject> FindAll(int someProperty)
{
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        var randomObjects = db.RandomObjects.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == someProperty);
    }
}
```

Each instance of RandomObject has a collection of the abstract Superclass. There are a fixed number of known subclasses (we can call them SubclassA and SubclassB if people need names).

I have been trying various Include statements such as this

```
randomObjects = randomObjects.Include(x => x.Superclasses.OfType<SubclassA>().SubclassAOnlyProperty);
```

If there is any clarification needed just let me know, I could definitely fill this post with all sorts of things I have tried.

Comment: `Include` and inheritance don't play nice together. The simple advice is don't use `Include` to get relations of multiple derived types in single query and especially don't use `Include` for this with TPT (until .NET 4.5 is out).

Comment: So what are my alternatives in terms of lazy/eager loading? The data I need is a list of this abstract subclass, and this data includes several relationships specific to only certain subclasses. How can I retrieve this TPT data without resorting to `Include`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
var result = MyContext.randomObjects
    .Select(r => new
    {
        RandomObj = r,
        SuperclassesOfTypeA = r.Superclasses.OfType<SubClassA>().Select(subA => new {
            obj = subA,
            SubclassAOnlyProperty = subA.SubclassAOnlyProperty
        }),
        AllSuperClasses = r.Superclasses
    })
    .ToList();
```

I think that would give you an in-memory collection of anonymous objects, where `RandomObj` would be the main object, `SuperclassesOfTypeA` would be a collection of anonymous objects representing your Super classes that are of type SubClassA, **with SubclassAOnlyProperty** eager loaded, and for good measure a collection of all your other superClasses.

Comment: Since my end goal is to have a RandomObject with a List<Superclass> that is the concatenation of the lists of subclasses, how might I go about ending up with that? Right now I just create a RandomObject from result.RandomObj and then set the List<Superclass> property to a concatenation of the Result.SubclassAList, Result.SubclassBList, etc. It seems pretty messy, but is it the best way?

Comment: @OpticalDelusion - I'm really not sure.  I think you should ask that as a new question.